# Agents is not working for me on latest opentest build

Tags: opentest

running opentest actor using "opentest actor" running on terminal and it's giving this issue to me, better if someone tell what to add on actor.yaml file to overcome this issue.

```
17.45.32 Running in working directory "/Users/ankit.rana/Desktop/opentest/actor1"
17.45.32 Loading configuration from "/Users/ankit.rana/Desktop/opentest/actor1/actor.yaml"
17.45.32 DEBUG: Test actor JAR versions:
17.45.32 DEBUG:   opentest-appium-0.0.1.jar: 2022-02-25 10:58 -0600 0.0.1-50659ecda06a8b79a41f24c1fdff05187324402b-dirty
17.45.32 DEBUG:   opentest-base-0.0.1.jar: 2022-02-25 10:58 -0600 0.0.1-50659ecda06a8b79a41f24c1fdff05187324402b-dirty
17.45.32 DEBUG:   opentest-selenium-0.0.1.jar: 2022-02-25 10:58 -0600 0.0.1-50659ecda06a8b79a41f24c1fdff05187324402b-dirty
17.45.32 WARN: Failed to log extension JARs
17.45.32 TRACE: The main class is org.getopentest.Main
17.45.32 ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/NashornScriptEngineFactory
    at org.getopentest.base.TestActor.createScriptEngine(TestActor.java:428)
    at org.getopentest.base.TestActor.<init>(TestActor.java:332)
    at org.getopentest.base.TestActor.<init>(TestActor.java:235)
    at org.getopentest.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 4 more
```